# Having a problem understanding the density charge per unit area in a coaxial cable (capacitor)

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, gauss-law

Given the following scenario, why is the charge per unit area not the same with opposite sign? I am finding it difficult to understand, since the charge per unit area for two parallel plates in a capacitor are related in this manner. How would the two relate in a cylindrical coaxial capacitor?

Sorry if I am not clear, I have been staring at this for 5 hours
[image]

Comment: losing it..................

Answer (score 1):

The coaxial cable will be neutral as a whole. This means the total charge per unit length must be zero. The charge per unit length of each conductor is $\lambda = \sigma C$, where $\sigma$ is the charge per unit area and $C$ is the circumference around which the charge is distributed. This means
$$|\sigma_1|C_1 = |\sigma_2|C_2$$
$$|\sigma_1|(2\pi R_1)=|\sigma_2|(2\pi R_2)$$
$$|\sigma_1| R_1 = |\sigma_2| R_2$$

Answer (score 1):

For a cylindrical geometry like a coaxial cable, the capacitance is usually stated as a capacitance per unit length where the charge density $\lambda$ is charge per unit length of  each conductor. The charge resides on the outer surface of the inner conductor and the inner wall of the outer conductor.

The capacitance per unit length is
$$\frac{C}{L}=\frac{2\pi k \epsilon_o}{ln(\frac{b}{a})}\tag{1}$$

where $b$ = outside radius (m), $a$ = inside radius (m) $k$ = dielectric constant (or relative permittivity) (unit less) $\epsilon_o$ = permittivity of free space (Farad/m).

For the parallel plate capacitor, the capacitance is is usually stated as capacitance per unit area, where the charge density $\lambda$ is charge per unit area.

$$\frac{C}{A}=\frac{k\epsilon_o}{d}\tag{2}$$

where $d$ is the separation between the plates.

Note that the units for capacitance $C$ in eq's (1) and (2) are the same, namely, farads.

Regardless of whether it is a coaxial capacitor or a parallel plate capacitor, although one conductor has a net negative charge the other has an equal amount of net positive charge, as it is the result of electrons being moved from one plate to the other. The total net charge is zero.

For the derivation of equations (1) and (2) see

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capcyl.html#c2
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/pplate.html#c1

Hope this helps.